# Put another fields with the nested JSON structure to pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, normalize

I am trying to put other fields from the json after normalize the nested part. I had followed some examples like I need but I don't understand why  the error : KeyError: 'phone Number'

In others words I need put another fields from the json in order to complet the neested fields and get a better structure in my panda dataframe

This is my code :

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data ={
  "consumer": {
    "phoneNumber": "3156578877",
    "channelId": "83",
    "appId": "APP_DAVIPLATA",
    "moduleId": "MA_PSE_VNZ",
    "sessionId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "appVersion": "16.1.1",
    "soVersion": "Android 11",
    "agentInfo": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36",
    "ipDevice": "163.111.221.230"
  },
  "transactionHeader": {
    "transactionType": "LOG",
    "transactionId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "transactionDate": "2018-07-03T17:54:36.762-05:00"
  },
  "transactionDetail": {
    "logType": "ANALITICA_OPERACIONAL",
    "MediaTarjetId": "PSE_VNZ_1",
    "Consumer": {
      "phoneNumber": "3156578877",
      "channelId": "83",
      "appId": "APP_DAVIPLATA",
      "moduleId": "MA_PSE_VNZ",
      "sessionId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "appVersion": "16.1.1",
      "soVersion": "Android 11",
      "agentInfo": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36",
      "ipDevice": "163.111.221.230"
    },
    "Transaction": {
      "transactionType": "LOG",
      "transactionId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "transactionDate": "2018-07-03T17:54:36.762-05:00"
    },
    "Client": {
      "identificationType": "CC",
      "identificationNumber": "1027868487",
      "documentExpeditionDate": "2009-05-10",
      "documentExpeditionPlace": "Bogota"
    },
    "Product": {
      "productCode": "DVP_CO",
      "productNumber": "3158765639"
    },
    "Messages": {
      "OperationalAnalytics": [
        {
          "nameField": "fecha_transaccion",
          "valueField": "2022071518:35:50",
          "valueFormat": "YYYYMMDDHH:MM:SS"
        },
        {
          "nameField": "nombre_transaccion",
          "valueField": "DEBITO PAGO",
          "valueFormat": "String"
        },
        {
          "nameField": "valor",
          "valueField": "5300",
          "valueFormat": "Number"
        },
        {
          "nameField": "referencia_destino",
          "valueField": "3156547865",
          "valueFormat": "String"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['transactionDetail','Messages','OperationalAnalytics'],meta = [['consumer','phoneNumber'], 'transactionHeader'])

KeyError: 'phoneNumber'
```

*In this code some like  I need it worked*

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    {
        "company": "Google",
        "tagline": "Dont be evil",
        "management": {"CEO": "Sundar Pichai"},
        "department": [
            {"name": "Gmail", "revenue (bn)": 123},
            {"name": "GCP", "revenue (bn)": 400},
            {"name": "Google drive", "revenue (bn)": 600},
        ],
    },
    {
        "company": "Microsoft",
        "tagline": "Be What's Next",
        "management": {"CEO": "Satya Nadella"},
        "department": [
            {"name": "Onedrive", "revenue (bn)": 13},
            {"name": "Azure", "revenue (bn)": 300},
            {"name": "Microsoft 365", "revenue (bn)": 300},
        ],
    },
  
]
result = pd.json_normalize(
    data, "department", ["company", "tagline", ["management", "CEO"]]
)
result
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json in your working example is a list of dictionaries while the one you are trying to transform is a dictionary.

You can access the dictionary elements directly with `data[key]` and convert them to dataframes that you will concatenate... One tricky part of your example are the keys in 'OperationalAnalytics'. I guess you would want the `nameField` *values* to be column names so that you get one line per transaction. This can be achieved by setting the `nameField` column to index and transposing:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([data["consumer"]])["phoneNumber"],
            pd.DataFrame([data["transactionHeader"]]),
            pd.DataFrame(data['transactionDetail']['Messages']['OperationalAnalytics']
                        ).set_index('nameField')[['valueField']].T.reset_index(drop=True)
          ], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  phoneNumber transactionType                         transactionId                transactionDate fecha_transaccion nombre_transaccion valor referencia_destino
0  3156578877             LOG  3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6  2018-07-03T17:54:36.762-05:00  2022071518:35:50        DEBITO PAGO  5300         3156547865
```

Edit: to get the result of your linked picture, it's actually simpler (although I don't get why you'd want a transaction on several rows):

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([data["consumer"]])["phoneNumber"],
            pd.DataFrame([data["transactionHeader"]]),
            pd.DataFrame(data['transactionDetail']['Messages']['OperationalAnalytics'])[['nameField', 'valueField']]
          ], axis=1).ffill()
```